# Ffmpeg not copying location metadata

Tags: video, ffmpeg, metadata, geolocation

I'm converting vidoes and even though I"m using -map_metadata 0

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -map_metadata 0 output.mp4
```

*The above code defaults to libx264/libvo_aacenc.*

The location metadata is not copied, even though ffmpeg recognizes it.

```
Metadata:
major_brand     : isom
minor_version   : 0
compatible_brands: isom3gp4
creation_time   : 2014-03-15 21:38:04
location        : +30.0854+037.8395/
location-eng    : +30.0854+037.8395/
```

The output.mp4 has this metadata

```
Metadata:
major_brand     : isom
minor_version   : 512
compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
creation_time   : 2014-03-15 21:38:04
encoder         : Lavf55.50.100
```

I've tried using

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -f ffmetadata FFMETADATAFILE
```

which copies the metadata and the **location** but then when I copy it back to

```
ffmpeg -i output.mp4 -i FFMETADATAFILE -map_metadata 1 -codec copy outputNew.mp4
```

The location does not copy.

P.s Also why does ffmpeg by default (when not using -map_metadata 0) not copy the tagged date but rewrites it with the conversion date, I assume people want to know when the video was taken not when it was converted.

Comment: I know this is a year old, but just in case it's helpful I cannot reproduce this using the latest version of `ffmpeg`.

Comment: it seems like an old issue https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/4209