# ffmpeg not mapping all input metadata

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, metadata, media-info

I have the exact same issue as this post : [Ffmpeg not copying location metadata](https://superuser.com/questions/795547/ffmpeg-not-copying-location-metadata) .
I convert wav to flac then back to wav when needed and i would like to keep original metadata as well.
I tried with many ffmpeg versions including the latest one.
My metadata file looks like this :

```
General
Complete name=C:\dev\test\wav\input_file.wav
Format=Wave
File size=218 KiB
Duration=2 s 160 ms
Overall bit rate mode=Constant
Overall bit rate=828 kb/s
Track name=FXName metadata
Track Position=0
Original Album=Source metadata
Encoded by=Pro Tools
Genre=Whatever Category
Description=This is a random description
Original Released date=2017
Recorded date=2017 / 2017-04-02
Encoded date=
Writing application=Soundminer
Copyright=2017  
Comment=This is a useless comment but i really wish it would be on output file
```

And my ffmpeg command looks like this :

```
\path\to\ffmpeg.exe -y -i input_file.flac -i metadata.txt -map_metadata 1 output_file.wav
```

Finally i use [MediaInfo](https://mediaarea.net/fr/MediaInfo) to compare original wav file an the one i converted from flac and i miss "track position", "original album", "Description", "Original release date", etc...

[image: MediaInfo Screenshot]